# Update-SPProfilePhotoStore executing successfully but not Profile updating photos in sharepoint 2013

Tags: user-profile, profile-sync, ad, synchronization

I'm running this command in powershell **Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 -MySiteHostLocation http://mysite.mydomain.local** It's executing successfully but the profile pictures are not updating.

I have also tried using this [Bulk Upload and Update User Profile Photos in SharePoint 2013.](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Bulk-Upload-and-Update-2c27437e/file/133553/1/Upload-ProfilePhotos_v1.1.zip)
but no updating and no error.

Assistance guys?

Comment: Have you set the import picture URL mapping and run a full profile sync? You should run the command only after that

Comment: In your MySite, do you have GUID'ed pictures (file names)? It would be located in the `Profile Pictures` folder in `https://<mySiteHostUrl/User%20Photos/`

Answer (score 0):

My Mistake is that I was using **SharePoint Active Directory Import**  to import picture property instead of **sharePoint Profile Synchronization**. The question was already answered here [Importing the Profile Picture from AD using ADI & ADFS](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/113584/importing-the-profile-picture-from-ad-using-adi-adfs)